# Adding outline around Switcher

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, border

I using the following component package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-switch-selector
To make it look like such
[image]

So far I have done the below but still missing border. How can I add the border outline and that the transition of outline matches the highlight when switching

```
<SwitchSelector
    onChange={onChange}
    options={[
        { label: 'Milestone', value: 'Milestone' },
        { label: 'Activity', value: 'Activity' },
        ]}
    initialSelectedIndex={0}
    fontColor={'#767676'}
    backgroundColor={'#FFFFFF'}
    wrapperBorderRadius={30}
    selectedFontColor={'#526FD6'}
    selectedBackgroundColor={'#EEF1FB'}
    optionBorderRadius={30}
/>
```

**My outcome**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have added `border` and `selectionIndicatorMargin` Props it should fix your issue.

```
<SwitchSelector 
      onChange={onChange} 
      options={[ { label: 'Milestone', value: 'Milestone' }, { label: 'Activity', value: 'Activity' }, ]} 
      initialSelectedIndex={0} 
      fontColor={ '#767676'} 
      backgroundColor={ '#FFFFFF'} 
      wrapperBorderRadius={30} 
      selectedFontColor={'#526FD6'} 
      selectedBackgroundColor={ '#EEF1FB'} 
      optionBorderRadius={30} 
      border={ '1px solid #f7f7f7'} 
      selectionIndicatorMargin={0} 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that help. Any way I could add a blue border around the select/active option like there is in reference image on top most?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the right way but what I ended but doing in addition to @amir-naeem 's solution was add the below

```
selectedBackgroundColor={'#EEF1FB; outline: solid thin; border-radius: inherit; outline-color: #526FD6;'}
```

so passing CSS directly in prop